# Issue with CanCan resource loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm using CanCan and I've run into an error I'm having trouble diagnosing.

Some users testing my application have received `NoMethodError: undefined method 'where' for nil:NilClass` originating from the line noted below.

Under what circumstances would `load_and_authorize_resource` leave `@jobs` as `nil` at that point?

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    if Job::STATES.include? params[:state]
      if params[:state] == 'in_progress'
        @jobs = @jobs.where(['state = ? or state = ?', params[:state], 'needs_confirmation'])
      else
        ###################################################
        # Error thrown here
        @jobs = @jobs.where(['state = ?', params[:state]])
        ###################################################
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And the relevent CanCan code:

```
if user.role? :employee
  can :read, Job do |j|
    (j.employee == user) or ( j.employee == nil )
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant `cancan` code?

Comment: edited with appropriate CanCan code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing `Job.where(...)` - you are getting that error because you are indeed calling `where` on a *nil* instance variable.  I personally do not rely too much on `load_resource`, there's no harm in being explicit.

Comment: I'm using `load_and_authorize_resource` because it handles sorting out only the jobs that the current user is authorized to see. I agree that there is no harm in being explicit, but I don't understand why the helper method is failing in this situation. It's purpose is to set the `@jobs` variable, so I don't see why it remains `nil`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked your authorisation?  It's possible the current user is not able to access the resource, hence it's loaded as nil.  Set your auth to `can :manage, :all` and see if `@jobs` is nil or not.  You might also want to handle what you do inside `jobs#index` differently depending on the user auth - check CanCan docs for details on this.

Comment: I think it has to do with authorization, because users with an `admin` role that `can :manage, :all` do not have this issue. This is only happening for users with the `employee` role shown in the CanCan code.   But that role is clearly authorized to read certain jobs, so I don't know what would cause `load_resource` to return `nil`. If there are no matching jobs, it should return an empty array.

Comment: Found why: [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks). Abilities defined in blocks need to be given the SQL condition string or else they will not set the instance variable in `load_resource`. Your solution is the correct one.